# Workflows and field-level security

Tags: workflow, field-level-security

I've got a workflow that triggers a field update (checkbox). I would like to restrict this checkbox to read-only for everybody except System Administrator. However, if a non-Sys Admin causes the workflow to trigger, will this be a problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workflows are not dependent on FLS. They will fire and update fields regardless of if the users causing the workflow to fire has access to that field.

Essentially they run as a "system" context.

Comment: Great. That's what I thought, just been a while so wanted to confirm. Thanks!